# Java EE 6 (spring mvc) : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I've just started learning Java EE 6.

I used a URL like `http://localhost:8080/SElabWeb-war/testhello.htm` to access my page.

Unfortunately, one error occurred:

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

Below are my XML settings:

web.xml:

```
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

redirect.jsp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <% response.sendRedirect("testhello.htm"); %>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
  <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
          p:suffix=".jsp"  />


    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean class="com.SElabWem.testContoller.HelloServerController" name="/testhello.htm"
               p:helloServer-ref="helloServer"/>
```

my applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean name = "helloServer" class= "com.SElabWem.test.HelloServer" /    >
```

I tried to change

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

but the URL `http://localhost:8080/SElabWeb-war/testhello.htm` is not correct.

I wonder whether there is a path between SElabWeb-war and testhello.htm.
such like

`/SElabWeb-war/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/testhello.htm`

but I can't find root oath config.

Comment: How do you configure your Handler Mappings...Using XML config or Annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a handler mapping defined to route your request to a controller ? Read this http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping for a reference . If you are using @Request and @Controller , DispatcherServlet enables DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping by default .